# extract portion of file name using gsub()

Tags: r

I'm reading multiple .txt files using `list.file()` and `file.path()`. Just wanted to parse the full path names and extract the portion after the last “/” and before the “.”

Here is the structure of file path names :

`"C:/Users/Alexandre/Desktop/COURS/FORMATIONS/THESE/PROJET/RESULTATS/Vessel features/Fusion/OK/SAT-DPL192C.txt"`

The code I've tried

```
# l <- list.files(pattern = "SAT(.+)*.txt")
# f <- file.path(getwd(), c=(l))
f <- c("C:/Users/Alexandre/Desktop/COURS/FORMATIONS/THESE/PROJET/RESULTATS/Vessel features/Fusion/OK/SAT-DPL192C.txt", "C:/Users/Alexandre/Desktop/COURS/FORMATIONS/THESE/PROJET/RESULTATS/Vessel features/Fusion/OK/SAT-DPL193D.txt")
d <- lapply(f, read.delim)
names(d) <- gsub(".*/(.*)..*", "1", f)
```

Last string give `[1] "1" "1"` instead of  `[1] "DPL192C" "DPL193D"` etc...

I've also tried the syntax like `".*/(.+)*..*` for the portion to conserv with same result.

Comment: How about `gsub(".*([^/]+)\\..*","\\1",f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.` is a special character, so you need to escape it. Please, when you want to grab the captured expression, you need to use `\\1`, not just `1`. Try this:

```
gsub(".*/(.*)\\..*", "\\1", f)
# [1] "SAT-DPL192C" "SAT-DPL193D"
```